# misdirected xymatrix arrow heads with certain fonts

Tags: xy-pic

I'd like to use `$\mathsf{C}$` rather than `$\mathcal{C}$` for categories. However, when I use the former in the first displayed equation, the top arrowhead (the arrow labelled `L`) points northwest, rather than southwest, as you'd expect. In the second displayed equation, with the wrong font, this arrow points in the correct direction. If I unload all the packages except xy, the problem disappears.

Any idea what's going on?

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{txfonts} 
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{dialogue}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmidx}%for the index
\makeindex{idx}
\makeindex{nidx}%index of notation
\makeindex{cidx}%index of categories
\newcommand{\idx}{\index{idx}}
\newcommand{\nidx}{\index{nidx}}
\newcommand{\cidx}{\index{cidx}}

\usepackage[pdfborder=0, hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[all,pdftex]{xy}
\newdir{ >}{{}*!/-10pt/@{>}}

\begin{document}

$$\xymatrix{ \mathsf{C} \ar[r]|U & \mathsf{D} \ar@{->}@/_3ex/[l]_L^\perp \ar@/^3ex/[l]^R_{\perp} }$$
$$\xymatrix{ \mathcal{C} \ar[r]|U & \mathsf{D} \ar@{->}@/_3ex/[l]_L^\perp \ar@/^3ex/[l]^R_{\perp} }$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Strange issue. It seems caused by `txfonts`, but it doesn't show if you use `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` instead of `\usepackage{txfonts}`. Note that the packages I recommend fix the numerous misfeatures of `txfonts` and are actively maintained.

Comment: @egreg: when I replace `txfonts` with `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`, the problem switches: the arrow is in the wrong direction for `\mathcal C` but correct for `\mathsf C`. Do you know why that might happen?

Comment: @ArunDebray I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: That's very strange; in any case, the problem goes away if I switch to a different font's `\mathcal`, e.g. by calling `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}`, or by adding a small amount of space (about 0.5ex) after the `\mathcal C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\newdir{ >}{{}*!/-10pt/@{>}}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
  \mathsf{C} \ar[r]|U & \mathsf{D} \ar@{->}@/_3ex/[l]_L^\perp \ar@/^3ex/[l]^R_{\perp}
}
\]

\[
\xymatrix{
  \mathcal{C} \ar[r]|U & \mathcal{D} \ar@{->}@/_3ex/[l]_L^\perp \ar@/^3ex/[l]^R_{\perp}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that you shouldn't pass the `pdftex` option (but it's not relevant to the issue).

[image]

If I change `\usepackage{txfonts}` into `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`, the problem disappears:

[image]

The NewTX fonts are an edited version of TXfonts, fixing the (many) misfeatures of the latter, especially with regards to spacing.

You might want to look at `tikz-cd` (it works also with `txfonts`, but I don't recommend it).

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3em]
\mathsf{C} \arrow[r,"U" description] &
  \mathsf{D}
  \arrow[l,bend right=50,"\perp","L" swap]
  \arrow[l,bend left=50,"R","\perp" swap]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! The {newtxtext,newtxmath} packages, which I hadn't heard of, fix my problem. Thank you!