# bending xypic arrow head is inconsistently oriented

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

I've been using nearly identical LaTeX code to typeset several adjoint triples. In all but one the arrowheads point as they should, but one of them is messed up. Here's a minimal working example, but with one catch: it displays correctly. (This isn't the case in my long manuscript. For some reason, this is the only diagram that doesn't display properly.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%xymatrix
\usepackage[all,pdftex, cmtip]{xy}
\newdir{ >}{{}*!/-10pt/@{>}}
\newdir{> }{{}*!/10pt/@{>}}

\begin{document}

\[\xymatrix{
    \mathsf{C}  \ar[r]|U
    & \mathsf{D}  \ar@/^3ex/[l]^R_{\perp} \ar@/_3ex/[l]_L^\perp
}\]

\end{document}
```

The messed up arrowhead is the one on the arrow labeled $L$. In my version, it points south-east. Can I add some code to force the top arrowhead to point south-west?

Comment: What is `\Cc`? Please make your code compilable. If this code does not show the falsy output, we can not help you. You have to minimize your "long manuscript" until you find the culprit part and show it to us. If this MWE is supposed to display correctly, we would have to guess what your actual problem is.

Comment: Is the problem related to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279060/55879)?

Comment: Wow. I mean yes. Though embarrassingly it wasn't until I saw the name at the end (after reading the entire post) that I realized that I'd asked the question.

Comment: I now have a circular problem because I just commented out newtxmath to fix a problem with font sizing that was affecting the display of a blackboard bold capital Delta.

Comment: Update: following Arun's suggestion on the original post, I added a small amount of space \, after the \mathsf{C} and that solved the problem. Thanks Arun!

Answer (score 1):

In case you did not know the package `tikz-cd`: Here is an implementation of what you want with it.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{% taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/143131
    ,no line/.style={%
        ,draw=none
        ,commutative diagrams/every label/.append style={/tikz/auto=false}
    }
}
\newcommand*{\cC}{A}

\begin{document}    
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
    \cC \arrow{r}[description,name=U]{U}\arrow[bend left=40]{r}[name=L]{L} & D \arrow[bend left=40]{l}[name=R]{R} \arrow[from=R, to=U, no line, pos=.65]{}{\perp}\arrow[from=L, to=U, no line, pos=.65]{}{\perp}
\end{tikzcd}
\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I have a temporary fix using tikz-cd, but I'd prefer to solve the problem in xypic for global consistency of style. (All of the other diagrams are drawn in xypic.)